# .eslintignore does not work in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, eslint

I am using Visual Studio 15.8.6 (Visual Studio 2017) and am trying to exclude the Scripts folder of my site only from ESLint as this is where I have my javascript library files. I have added a .eslintignore file to the project root (not the solution folder) and included in the project. I have tried the following lines (not at the same time):

**/Scripts/*.js

./Scripts/*.js

Scripts/*.js

/Scripts/*.js

I restarted Visual Studio each time, but none of these have worked. This tool is useless to me if I cannot exclude third party javascript from the validation. What exactly is the trick to getting this to work in Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code).

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Any progress?